# Writing function to help merge to different datasets

Tags: r, function

I am attempting to merge two different datasets: `nflfastrpbp` and `routes.merging`.

While both datasets have identifying factors for each game:

nflfastrpbp = `game_id, old_game_id`

routes.merging = `GameID`

... they are not matches.

Here is a look at the `nflfastrpbp` data:

```
A tibble: 48,514 x 8
   game_id        old_game_id  week home_team away_team game_date  pass_defense_1_player_id pass_defense_1_player_name
   <chr>          <chr>       <int> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>      <chr>                    <chr>                     
 1 2020_01_ARI_SF 2020091311      1 SF        ARI       2020-09-13 NA                       NA                        
 2 2020_01_ARI_SF 2020091311      1 SF        ARI       2020-09-13 NA                       NA                        
 3 2020_01_ARI_SF 2020091311      1 SF        ARI       2020-09-13 NA                       NA                        
 4 2020_01_ARI_SF 2020091311      1 SF        ARI       2020-09-13 NA                       NA                        
 5 2020_01_ARI_SF 2020091311      1 SF        ARI       2020-09-13 NA                       NA                        
 6 2020_01_ARI_SF 2020091311      1 SF        ARI       2020-09-13 NA                       NA                        
 7 2020_01_ARI_SF 2020091311      1 SF        ARI       2020-09-13 NA                       NA                        
 8 2020_01_ARI_SF 2020091311      1 SF        ARI       2020-09-13 NA                       NA                        
 9 2020_01_ARI_SF 2020091311      1 SF        ARI       2020-09-13 NA                       NA                        
10 2020_01_ARI_SF 2020091311      1 SF        ARI       2020-09-13 NA                       NA
```

And here is a look at the `routes.merging` data:

```
# A tibble: 80,676 x 6
   EventID GameID Season  Week OffensiveTeam DefensiveTeam
     <int>  <int>  <int> <int> <chr>         <chr>        
 1      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs       
 2      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs       
 3      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs       
 4      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs       
 5      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs       
 6      25   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs       
 7      25   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs       
 8      25   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs       
 9      25   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs       
10      45   2793   2020     1 Chiefs        Texans       
# ... with 80,666 more rows
```

**What I  am trying to do:** I am attempting to get the `game_id` from the `nflfastrpbp` data onto the `routes.merging` data and, of course, matching it up with the correct games so that I can merge the two together (specifically to pull the `pass_defense_player` information from `nflfastrpbp` to `routes.merging`.)

I've been trying to write a function but cannot figure it out.

If it helps, here is reprex for each dataset (I will include the `2020_01_ARI_SF` game from both for helping in matching).

**`nflfastrpbp` reprex:**

```
structure(list(game_id = c("2020_01_ARI_SF", "2020_01_ARI_SF", 
"2020_01_ARI_SF", "2020_01_ARI_SF", "2020_01_ARI_SF"), old_game_id = c("2020091311", 
"2020091311", "2020091311", "2020091311", "2020091311"), week = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), home_team = c("SF", "SF", "SF", "SF", "SF"), 
    away_team = c("ARI", "ARI", "ARI", "ARI", "ARI"), game_date = c("2020-09-13", 
    "2020-09-13", "2020-09-13", "2020-09-13", "2020-09-13"), 
    pass_defense_1_player_id = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), pass_defense_1_player_name = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

**`routes.merging` reprex:**

```
structure(list(EventID = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 45L), GameID = c(2805L, 
2805L, 2805L, 2805L, 2805L), Season = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L), Week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), OffensiveTeam = c("49ers", 
"49ers", "49ers", "49ers", "Cardinals"), DefensiveTeam = c("Cardinals", 
"Cardinals", "Cardinals", "Cardinals", "49ers")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), groups = structure(list(EventID = c(30L, 45L), GameID = c(2805L, 
2805L), .rows = structure(list(1:4, 5L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I hope all that made sense.

**EDIT - Expected Outcome:** The expected outcome is the `routes.merging` DF with a new column, `id.for.merging`, that is the `game_id` from the `nflfastrpbp` DF ... again, matched up correctly by game.

```
 EventID GameID Season  Week OffensiveTeam DefensiveTeam id.for.merging
     <int>  <int>  <int> <int> <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         
 1      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_01_HOU_KC
 2      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_01_HOU_KC
 3      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_01_HOU_KC
 4      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_01_HOU_KC
 5      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_01_HOU_KC
 6      25   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_01_HOU_KC
 7      25   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_01_HOU_KC
 8      25   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_01_HOU_KC
 9      25   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_01_HOU_KC
10      45   2793   2020     1 Chiefs        Texans        2020_01_HOU_KC
```

**EDIT #2:** The GameID from `nflfastrpbp` and GameID from `routes.merging` DO NOT match. That is why I am here for help. As seen in the above Expected Outcome, I need the `GameID` from `nflfastrpbp` to be on the data for `routes.merging` so that I can merge all the data from `nflfastrpbp` onto the `routes.merging` DF.

I started to write a `function` that used `paste` and got as far as `2020_0` but couldn't figure out how to grab the `week` (which is `01` in the above example ... but will go all the way to 17 with the full data) and then the `away_team` followed by the `home_team` ... so `2020_01_HOU_KC`

**EDIT #3** There *is not a column to match*.

I am trying to CREATE that column by recreating the `game_id` column in `nflfastpbp` within the `routes.merging` DF so that I can merge the two together on that *newly created column.*

So, I started to write this function:

```
testing <- function(x) {
  add.column.nflfastrpbp.to.routes.merged <- paste("2020_0")
}

routes.merging$id.for.merging <- testing()
```

And, in the `id.for.merging` column in `routes.merging` you can see it is working:

```
 EventID GameID Season  Week OffensiveTeam DefensiveTeam id.for.merging
     <int>  <int>  <int> <int> <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         
 1      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_0        
 2      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_0        
 3      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_0        
 4      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_0        
 5      15   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_0        
 6      25   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_0        
 7      25   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_0        
 8      25   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_0        
 9      25   2793   2020     1 Texans        Chiefs        2020_0        
10      45   2793   2020     1 Chiefs        Texans        2020_0        
# ... with 80,666 more rows
```

What I cannot figure out is how to finish writing that function to take all the information and correctly match the `game_id` from `nflfastrpbp` for all the unique games.

So, taking:

```
testing <- function(x) {
  add.column.nflfastrpbp.to.routes.merged <- paste("2020_0")
}
```

... and finishing it so that it outputs:

```
2020_01_ARI_SF

or 

2020_07_GB_HOU
```

into the newly created `id.for.merging` column.

To be clear:

2020 = year (not included in the data)

01 & 07 = week (included)

GB_HOU = away_team, home_towm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write a separate function to create a new column. But if you do want to, you can do this:

```r
testing <- function(df) {
    library(dplyr)
    with(df, # assumes `df` is a data structure like `routes.merging`
        paste0(
            "2020_", 
            sprintf("%02d", Week), 
            "_", 
            case_when( # away_team == "team_name" ~ "city"
                OffensiveTeam == "Texans" ~ "HOU", 
                OffensiveTeam == "Chiefs" ~ "KC",
                OffensiveTeam == "Cardinals" ~ "ARI",  
                OffensiveTeam == "49ers" ~ "SF", 
                # etc.
                OffensiveTeam == "Packers" ~ "GB" 
            ), 
            "_", 
            case_when( # home_team == "team_name" ~ "city"
                DefensiveTeam == "Texans" ~ "HOU", 
                DefensiveTeam == "Chiefs" ~ "KC", 
                DefensiveTeam == "Cardinals" ~ "ARI", 
                DefensiveTeam == "49ers" ~ "SF", 
                # etc.
                DefensiveTeam == "Packers" ~ "GB" 
            )
        )
    )
}

routes.merging$id.for.merging <- testing(routes.merging)
```

Otherwise, you can add the column directly like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
routes.merging <- mutate(routes.merging, 
    id.for.merging = paste0(
        "2020_", 
        sprintf("%02d", Week), 
        "_", 
        case_when( # away_team == "team_name" ~ "city"
            OffensiveTeam == "Texans" ~ "HOU", 
            OffensiveTeam == "Chiefs" ~ "KC", 
            OffensiveTeam == "Cardinals" ~ "ARI", 
            OffensiveTeam == "49ers" ~ "SF", 
            # etc.
            OffensiveTeam == "Packers" ~ "GB" 
        ), 
        "_", 
        case_when( # home_team == "team_name" ~ "city"
            DefensiveTeam == "Texans" ~ "HOU", 
            DefensiveTeam == "Chiefs" ~ "KC", 
            DefensiveTeam == "Cardinals" ~ "ARI", 
            DefensiveTeam == "49ers" ~ "SF", 
            # etc.
            DefensiveTeam == "Packers" ~ "GB" 
        )
    )
)
```

`sprintf("%02d", Week)` makes any single digit (e.g., "1") into double digits (e.g., "01"), and double digits stay double digits.

`case_when()` is a function in `dplyr` R package. The function allows you to vectorize multiple `ifelse()` statements. You will need to add more lines in `case_when()` for a complete list of the NFL teams, of course.

The output from using your reprex data structure looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   EventID, GameID [2]
  EventID GameID Season  Week OffensiveTeam DefensiveTeam id.for.merging
    <int>  <int>  <int> <int> <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         
1      30   2805   2020     1 49ers         Cardinals     2020_01_SF_ARI
2      30   2805   2020     1 49ers         Cardinals     2020_01_SF_ARI
3      30   2805   2020     1 49ers         Cardinals     2020_01_SF_ARI
4      30   2805   2020     1 49ers         Cardinals     2020_01_SF_ARI
5      45   2805   2020     1 Cardinals     49ers         2020_01_ARI_SF
```

Finally, merging:

```r
merged_data <- full_join(routes.merging, nflfastrpbp, by = c("id.for.merging" = "game_id"))
```

Run `?dplyr::join` or `?merge` to learn more about some other merge functions and options.

Comment: This is great! A lot easier than what I was trying to do, for sure. However, there is one issue ... if you look at the output you posted near the end, `2020_01_SF_ARI` switches to `2020_01_ARI_SF`. This won't merge correctly because `nflfastrpbp` uses `away_team` and `home_team` for the `game_id.` But, I think I can work around it ... just use the same code you provided in `nflfastrpbp` to make a new column and, instead of `Offensive` or `DefensiveTeam`, sub in `posteam` and `defteam` ... should line up perfectly after that. Thank you again!

Comment: You said the the ID column is like "[year]_[week]_[away_team]_[home_team]". So when it is like `2020_01_SF_ARI`, the away team is SF while the home team is ARI. In `2020_01_ARI_SF`, the away team is ARI and the home team is SF. It switches because the away/home (or offensive/defensive) teams switched.

Comment: Yes, but `away_team` and `home_team` do not change in the middle of the game. In this case, it should be `2020_01_ARI_SF` over the course of the entire `GameID`. Like I said though, not a big issue ... pretty sure I can correct it by running the same code on `nflfastrpbp`.